# How to fetch user's email address associated with Apple Pay Account from Apple Pay using JavaScript

Tags: applepayjs

I wanted to know if Apple has an API which we can use to fetch user's email address associated with apple pay account.

FYI I am using apple pay js (ApplePaySession) for apple pay. 
Or is there another way to fetch user's email address from Apple pay in JavaScript.

Thank You!

Comment: @Thunder any chance you have a clue about the answer to my question ?

Comment: check the answer below, mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the user authorizes the transaction, you will get the **shippingContact** Object like this:-

```
{
"locality": “India",
"country": "India",
"postalCode": "95014-2083",
"administrativeArea": "CA",
"emailAddress": “sachin@example.com”,
"familyName": “Tendulkar",
"addressLines": [
"1 Infinite Loop"
],
"givenName": “Sachin",
"countryCode": "INDIA",
"phoneNumber": "(408) 555-5555"
}
```

from this object you can access the email id.

Comment: Thanks @Thunder! When does the user input the email address("sachin@example.com") in the system. Is it when checking out and paying or while registering for apple pay. I wanted to know if we can get the email id with which the user has registered for Apple Pay

Comment: No I modified value of fields with dummy contents but you will get a JSON object like this

Comment: You can take email from this JSON object , this is the same email of user which is associated with apple play account.hope this clarify your question please upvote and accept dear

Comment: I resolved the issue. Along with your answer, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applepayjs/applepaypayment/1916097-shippingcontact this link helped. As explained in the link, we have to pass the "requiredShippingContactFields" in the payment request and then we can access the email

Comment: Yes correct, I am glad being a part of your solution for this issue :-) if you want you can upvote this too Neha

Comment: Thanks again for the answer, but unfortunately I cannot upvote the your answer yet

Comment: No problem it's ok 

Answer (score 2):

The email address is provided within the `onpaymentauthorized` callback of your ApplePaySession.

**Note:** It is an inherited property, so it may be somewhat difficult to find in your developer console (in Chrome you've got to drill down into the event's __proto__ property).

You must specifically ask for the email address by including a `requiredShippingContactFields` property in your payment request:

```
    requiredShippingContactFields: [
        'phone',
        'email'                 
    ]
```

And the email address will be available like so:

```
var session = new ApplePaySession(2, myPaymentRequest);

session.onpaymentauthorized = function(event){
    console.log(event.payment.shippingContact.shippingAddress);
};
```